# Black hole mergers vs formation of the solar system

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, solar-system

I understand there are questions about how black holes can collide and how the solar system formed. Angular momentum should prevent both. It isn't well understood how either one loses their initial angular momentum.

From the Wikipedia [Binary Black Hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_black_hole) article, this is called the Final parsec problem. Dynamical friction can explain how bound black hole pairs can form, but they should mostly be a few parsecs apart. If they are < $0.01$ parsec apart, gravitational radiation will cause them to merge. The only mechanism mentioned that can bridge the difference is the unusual case of 3 bound black holes.

[Angular momentum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_problem) says there is a similar problem for the formation of the solar system. It is a stub, but it references [Losing spin: the angular momentum problem](https://academic.oup.com/astrogeo/article/53/5/5.19/208905), which discusses the matter. Although 1% of the mass of the solar system is contained in its planets, they contain roughly 99% of the angular momentum. Why does the sun have so little? The parent cloud from which the solar system condensed had about 2.5 million x the angular momentum of the solar system. Where did it go? Apparently the data does not fit the models very well.

So do these articles summarize the current state of knowledge? Is enough known to say whether these have similar mechanisms? Are there other structures that should not be able to from?

Comment: Note that the final parsec problem is relevant only for (super)massive black holes.